# I am not understanding how this for loop is working c++

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   for int (i=0; i<100; i++)
   if (i%9 == 0) x = i;
   else x = -1;
   cout << x;
   return 0;
}
```

This snippet of code returns the value 99.

When i read it line by line I understand it like this.

1. Declare a variable x, assign it the value 0.
2. For i = 0, i is less than 100, increment i by 1.
3. if the remainder of i/9 is equal to 0, assign the value of i to x.
4. If it isn't set x to be equal to -1
5. Print out x

In the first step of the for loop i is assigned the value 0. 0 divided by 9 is equal to 0 which mets the conditions of the if statement so why would it not print out that x is equal to 0 instead of 99?

Comment: Your description doesn't really seem to match the code you've posted. Can you fix the code please?

Comment: For/else !! You made my day :) !!!

Comment: @GregHewgill This is a mid term preparation exam we did together in class, my professor has told us the answer is 99 and i have been having trouble figuring out why, that's the code that was given to us on the practice test.

Comment: Please tell your professor his code is garbage.

Comment: You sure you didn't drop a line of code or two when posting here? This code won't compile, much less produce an answer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Am i right in believing that the output is wrong then?

Comment: I hate questions like this. My first reaction is "that is just not valid code!", but then I think "Hang on, is it some weird C++14 or GNU extension that I don't know about".

Comment: @user3358064 if you believe in "garbage in == garbage out" then the output is spot on.

Comment: I am very sorry everyone, I did miss a line of code. I'm exhausted from studying all night i didnt even realize

Comment: The code you've posted does not compile. Once you fix that, use the debugger to step through the code and see what it's doing. The assignment was given to you for you to learn, not for us to explain to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Line By Line

> 1) Declare a variable `x`; assign it the value 0.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x=0;
}
```

> 2) For `i = 0`, `i` is less than 100, increment `i` by 1.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {};
}
```

> 3) If the remainder of `i/9` is equal to 0, assign the value of `i` to `x`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if(i%9==0)
        {
            x = i;
        }
    };
}
```

> 4) If it isn't set, `x` should equal -1:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if(i%9==0)
        {
            x = i;
        }

        else
        {
            x = -1;
        }
    };
}
```

> 5) Print out `x`

```
 #include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if(i%9==0)
        {
            x = i;
        }

        else
        {
            x = -1;
        }
    };
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://cpp.sh/7btv3) of last one.

### References to more C++ fun activities

> [worldbestlearn](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/cpp-tutorial-loop_exercises.htm)
>
> [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Exercises/Iterations)
>
> [course](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~wjk/C++Intro/RobMillerE5.html)

Comment: I think I understand it now after i read it over and over. The limit i can go to is 100, so it iterates as many times as possible within the 100 iteration limit, and the last number that is divisible by 9 is 99. Which was assigned to x

Comment: @user3358064 formatted , for better readbility. Any other questions ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct. Each time through the loop, `x` gets either the value of `i` or the value `-1`. The last time through the loop, `i == 99` and `i % 9` is indeed 0, so `x` gets assigned the value `99`. Then `i` gets the value `100`, the loop exits, and the rest of the program prints the current value of `x`, which is `99`.

Note that the `if/else` is the body of the `for` loop. The loop doesn't exit just because `i%9` is 0 in the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the *single statement after the `for` loop* is inside the for loop. Note that `if ... else ...` is one statement (that contains other statements).

The exact same code should be better written as:

```
int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
   {
      if (i%9 == 0)
         x = i;
      else
         x = -1;
   }
   cout << x;
   return 0;
}
```

and now it should be easy to see why nothing is printed until the loop ends.